# get request to laravel api route not working in custom package

Tags: laravel, api, get, routes, request

I am working with laravel 5.4 to on a custom package. I have defined my routes on a seperate file `routes.php`. I am loading the routes file through a service provider.

The problem I am facing is that when I send `POST` requests to the routes the routes are working fine, but when I send `GET` requests, it redirects me to the login page.

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'api', 
    'middleware' => 'api']
    function(){
        Route::get('/users',function() {
            $users = \App\User::all();    
            return response()->json($users);
        });

        Route::post('/users',function() {
                $users = \App\User::all();    
                return response()->json($users);
            });

    });
```

My ServiceProvider

```
class UserServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{


    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
        $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__.'/routes.php');
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

}
```

`php artisan route:list`

`+--------+----------+-----------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | POST     | api/users                               |      | Closure                                                                    | api        |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/users                               |      | Closure                                                                    | api        |
|        | POST     | oauth/personal-access-tokens            |      | \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\PersonalAccessTokenController@store     | web,auth   |
|        | GET|HEAD | oauth/personal-access-tokens            |      | \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\PersonalAccessTokenController@forUser   | web,auth   |
|        | DELETE   | oauth/personal-access-tokens/{token_id} |      | \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\PersonalAccessTokenController@destroy   | web,auth   |
|        | GET|HEAD | oauth/scopes                            |      | \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ScopeController@all                     | web,auth   |
|        | POST     | oauth/token                             |      | \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController@issueToken        | throttle   |
|        | POST     | oauth/token/refresh                     |      | \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\TransientTokenController@refresh        | web,auth   |
|        | GET|HEAD | oauth/tokens                            |      | \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AuthorizedAccessTokenController@forUser | web,auth   |
|        | DELETE   | oauth/tokens/{token_id}                 |      | \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AuthorizedAccessTokenController@destroy | web,auth   |
|        | GET|HEAD | {path?}                                 |      | App\Http\Controllers\WelcomeController                                     | web        |
+--------+----------+-----------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+`

I am using `POSTMAN` to test my `routes`.

Please help.

Comment: have you tried naming your post/get routes differently to see if that works?

Comment: yes I have tried that. Any route other then `get` method does returns me the correct response. I am facing issues only with `get` routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a missing bracket to close the array and both your routes do exactly the same thing. How are you loading the views in the service provider?

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api', 'middleware' => 'api'], function() {

    Route::get('/users', function () {
        $users = \App\User::all();
        return response()->json($users);
    });

    Route::post('/users', function () {
        $users = \App\User::all();
        return response()->json($users);
    });

});
```

Edit : After reviewing your codes as per my comment request, the issue here is your global get route `GET|HEAD | {path?}`, this route will overlap with any other route in your app and this route has web and auth middleware, meaning it needs authentication. Delete this route and everything should work fine.

```
Route::get('/{path?}', 'WelcomeController');
```

Edit 2 : Since you need this, the other solution is to place your service provider above the `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class`

Comment: Thanks `@Sandeesh`. Sorry, I missed the closing `]` in the question. I am not loading any views. I am returning `json` responses.

Comment: Ye i can make out. But both the get and post routes do the exact same thing in your code. And do share your service provider code to understand how you load your routes.

Comment: Can you run `php artisan route:list` and show us the output?

Comment: sure. 
```POST            api/users       Closure     api 
GET|HEAD    api/users       Closure     api```

Comment: @besrabasant i've updated my answer to fix your issue. It's caused by a wildcard route which catches all your get routes and is wrapped with auth middleware. You need to remove that or change it.

Comment: I did a bit of tinkering and found that the `route` when defined in `routes/api.php` works as intended. but doesn't work when defined in Custom package routes.

Comment: @besrabasant just see my answer, when you define the route in api.php, it takes precedence to the global route catching all get routes. So it would work. But this isn't right, unless you intend it this way. But if you are really not understanding this, then just add your service provider above `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,` in the app  config file.

Comment: solved it by adding the `serviceprovider` above `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class`. That was part I was missing.

Comment: This solves your current issue. But this isn't the correct solution. You shouldn't have a  catch all get route point towards welcome controller.

Comment: Yeah. But I had to, since I  have a *React* frontend

Comment: Alright makes sense. I updated my answer with all the help i've provided in case anyone else stumbles on this with the same issue.